# Clearing creases via script

Tags: python, scripting, edges

[image]
I want to use mean crease in my python script, but i cant access its code via "edit source". I need a button which clears all creases on selected edges with single click, and put it in my custom pie menu. I've found some info on it : mean crease function is scripted with C. Any ideas how to get "mean crease" in python?

Comment: In object mode you find it in `obj.data.edges.crease`. While in edit mode you would need to use `bmesh.from_edit_mesh()` and get the [edge crease](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMLayerAccessEdge) from the [custom data layers](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html#customdata-access).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the line you need

> bpy.ops.transform.edge_crease(value=-1.0)

```
import bpy

class UIPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Crease Clear"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.active_object is not None) and (context.mode == "EDIT_MESH")

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("crease.clear", text='Crease Clear')

class OBJECT_OT_HelloButton(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "crease.clear"
    bl_label = "Crease Clear"
    country = bpy.props.StringProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.transform.edge_crease(value=-1.0)
        return{'FINISHED'}    

bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
```

[image]

Если ты хочешь чтобы кнопка осталась в системе, после перезапуска блендера, сохрани текст в файл с форматом .py и нажми последовательно эти кнопки

If you want the button to remain in the system, after restarting the blender, save the text in a file with the format .py and click these buttons sequentially

[image]

Comment: Thx alot. This code works for pie menu's too. Thats what i was looking for.